IDL error 'End of file encountered before end of program'
I am using IDL workspace but unable to get started because I get the error below. Note that I can work in the console without any error.
I am new to IDL and I would appreciate if anyone can help me address this error or link me to any relevant material. This link suggested to change directorate, which I did but got no luck.
PRO fileName
;start the application
  e = ENVI()
End

If I run any code, I get the error:
End of file encountered before end of program.
  At: C:\Users
Compilation error(s) in module 'name of file'. Attempt to call undefined procedure: fileName


Please show the real error, as a copy-pasted text block, and show the code you're trying to run, after running through the [mcve] exercise to see if that lets you find the problem all on your own.

It is hard to tell what you are doing, but if what you have quoted above is literally what you have in a file, then that would be a problem. Typically, to define a routine in IDL in a file, say my_routine.pro, then you would have:
pro my_routine
  ; valid IDL statements, like:
  e = envi()
end


I changed opening my editor from using new pro file to new envi extenstion, and this solved the problem.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
